# How to automate the battery usage analysis for iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, battery

We have a requirement to automate the battery usage analysis, this analysis should be performed in automatic during build or can be done in perfecto.Xcode instrument have option to do battery analysis , this tool main motive is to find fix battery usage issues. Is it possible to automate this process or any third party framework available to do this?

Waiting for your response

Comment: Any comments or thought on this ?